Why Set and List arn't equal although the contain same elements? (Kotlin)
I noticed the List and Set although contain same elements but the equals operator return false.
Meanwhile, if we compare List vs List or Set vs Set, it will return true (both inherit from Collection).
val list = listOf("abc")
val set = setOf("abc")

print(list == set) // false

val list2 = listOf("abc")
print(list == list2) // true

val set2 = setOf("abc")
print(set == set2) // true

I think the == operator should only consider whether the objects in the Collection are equal or not.

On Android, a Kotlin List is a java.util.List. That interface defines equals to return true "if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal". The Set::equals method has a similar specification.

"I think the == operator should only consider whether the objects in the Collection are equal or not." - Sorry mate, but what >you< think doesn't matter here.  That matters here is what the specification says.

How do you intend to consistently compare a list with a set anyway? For example, setOf("abc", "def") == setOf("def", "abc") is true (order does not matter). Should listOf("abc", "def") the considered equal to setOf("abc", "def") which is equal to setOf("def", "abc") which "you may think should be" equal to listOf("def", "bac")? But then listOf("def", "abc") is not equal to listOf("abc", "def") because order matters. And then there are cases when the inputs have duplicates, for example setOf("abc", "def", "def") == setOf("abc", "def") but it's a different behavior with listOf.

As @qrsngky explained in the comment, it is not possible for any List to be equal to any Set. This can be proved from first principles. By definition, the == operator must:

be symmetric: a == b implies b == a and vice versa.
be transitive: If a == b and b == c then it must be true that a == c.

Looking at the definition of equality for lists: the elements must be equal and in the same order.
But the definition of equality for sets ignores ordering: the two sets only need to contain the same elements, in any order. This is because conceptually sets don't have order, though in practice they do have an iteration order (which may or may not be deterministic).
Now if it were possible for lists to be equal to sets:
listOf(1, 2) == setOf(1, 2)
setOf(1, 2) == setOf(2, 1)
setOf(2, 1) == listOf(2, 1)
therefore listOf(2, 1) == listOf(1, 2) ???

but that is not correct; therefore lists cannot be equal to sets.
Workaround
If you want to compare a list to a set, you need to first decide whether you want the set's iteration order to be used in the comparison. If so, do this:
yourList == yourSet.toList()

To ignore order, do this:
yourList.toSet() == yourSet

or for better performance (by avoiding creation of temporary Set):
yourList.size == yourSet.size && yourSet.containsAll(yourList)

